# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- relevant music blogs and websites
- resources for public domain sheet music and other materials
- events, conferences, or meetups about musical topics
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3146).

Answer (score 11):

[image: IMSLP: Sharing the world's public domain music]

Answer (score 11):

[image: MuseScore - Create, play and print beautiful sheet music]

Comment: I'm all for advertisiing MuseScore, but is there a source for the claim on the bottom of the ad?

Comment: No other than they claim it on their web site. I changed the bottom text from "WORLD’S MOST POPULAR NOTATION SOFTWARE" to "FREE NOTATION SOFTWARE", which at least we know to be true...

Comment: @awe: What about *open-source notation software* instead? Maybe nobody cares about the nuances of both terms, but the second seems more valuable for me than the first.

Comment: @Helio: "open-source" is something that only developers know what means. Both our site here at Music.SE and this particular software, are targetting musicians, not developers. Although there are probably a high percentage developers here since it is the SE network, it is not developers that are the primary target of the ad. The original comment from Richard was for the text that was before I changed it, which was "WORLD’S MOST POPULAR NOTATION SOFTWARE". See the [revisions](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3160/revisions) of this post for the original image.

Answer (score 7):

[image: musictheory.net]

Comment: I'd be really interested to know where the downvotes come from. If someone has a better free music theory intro site I'm all ears. If someone also doesn't like the graphic, feel free to make a better one.

Comment: I wish I found this one earlier.

Comment: @Dom: I would like to suggest a redesign for this advertisement, so it becomes a bit cleaner: i.stack.imgur.com/Z2o0Z.png

Answer (score 3):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Musician's Notebook: The perfect notebook for musicians]